# Convert only certain xml characters to their HTML entities (&#nnn;)

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding

I have a problem where I have some html like this

```
<p>There is the unfinished business of Taiwan, eventual “reunification”...a communiqué committing</p>
```

In that text string I would not want to change the < and > to & lt ; and ^ gt ;

However I would want to convert the quotes around “reunification” and the é in communiqué.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will likely have to write your own htmlentities() replacement function. The easiest way would probably be to apply htmlentities(), and then replace < (or the numeric one, can't remember which php gives) with a <, and whatever other characters you want.

You might also be interested in Markdown, it is similar to what you are trying to accomplish, and might fit your needs.

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/
http://michelf.com/projects/php-markdown/

Comment: I basically did a variation on this where I removed < and > and a few other chars from get_html_translation_table() and using strtr() over that modified array.

Answer (score 0):

'<' is a reserved character in XML.  Section 2.3 of the XML standard strictly dictates that it MUST be escaped as either an entity or a character reference when used within character data.  It is only allowed to appear in its unescapsed form when used as XML markup, or within a comment, processing instruction, or a CDATA section. Why do you want to bypass that requirement?

Comment: I don't want to escape that character as I know my data doesn't contain any < or > apart from those that actually form the edge markers of the XML

Comment: If you want to put HTML markup inside of XML, you MUST either escape reserved characters, such as '<', or else put the HTML into a CDATA block, ie:  <MyXmlDoc><HtmlContent><![CDATA[<p>There is the unfinished business of Taiwan, eventual “reunification”...a communiqué committing</p>]]></HtmlContent></MyXmlDoc>